# Why do cables specify 75 Ω impedance when impedance is a two-dimensional quantity?

Tags: resistance, impedance, speakers, coax

As I understand it, impedance has an imaginary and a real part. To be able to perform any useful calculations, one needs to know both. Cables and speakers usually only say like "8 Ω" or "75 Ω". Is that purely resistive? If so, what is so special about 75 Ω that all coaxial cables have that resistance, and why are speakers are usually 2, 4, or 8 Ω?

Comment: Have a look at this similar question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93232/how-is-x%e2%84%a6-impedance-cable-defined/93254#93254

Comment: Not all coax cables are 75 ohm. 50 ohm is more common as well as others such as 93 ohm.

Comment: @KevinWhite 75 ohms far more common.   all that cable TV infrastructure adds up real quick.

Comment: @Jasen - possibly - virtually all other general purpose equipment such as  signal generators, function generators , oscilloscopes etc tend to be 50 ohm though. I personally have never owned or used a 75 ohm piece of equipment. (Except for cable TV and cable modem at home).

Answer (score 22):

The 75-ohm impedance associated with a transmission line is a so-called characteristic impedance, and it describes the behavior of high speed effects on the line. In particular, if you transmit a fast<sup>1</sup> pulse or fast sine wave over a transmission line, the voltage wave and current wave traveling over the line will have a 75-volt-per-ampere (i.e. ohm) ratio.

This value is useful when designing high speed systems that avoid reflections and ringing-- while an impulse travels smoothly along matched transmission lines, if the impedance suddenly changes then a reflection will occur, much like a window reflects a bit of light at the air-glass interface. These reflections can be a major practical problem that degrades signal integrity in communication systems and may cause damage to high power radio transmitters when not properly handled.

As it happens, 75 and 50 ohm lines are common values that got standardized for their various applications and can be manufactured with relative ease. The actual values are a consequence of fundamental physical constants, the cross sectional geometry of the cable, and the materials used in its fabrication.

If your characteristic impedance is reactive, you are also modeling the losses on the line; this loss is often instead modeled as attenuation per distance in dB/m or similar, which is more convenient for practical calculations than a complex impedance.

On the other hand, speaker impedance is a more vague, approximate value given to estimate power handling and amplifier requirements. Reactive component aside, it's highly frequency dependent anyway and is more of an average (see example charts at https://www.aperionaudio.com/blogs/aperion-audio-blog/the-truth-about-speaker-impedance)

<sup>1</sup> fast enough that the transmission line is long relative to the rise time of the signal. At audio frequencies, this kind of high frequency behavior only shows up when your transmission line is on the order of multiple km long.

Answer (score 13):

> *Why do cables specify 75 ohm impedance when impedance is a 2
> dimensional quantity?*

Cable characteristic impedance is a big subject

When a coax cable is specified as being 50 Ω or 75 Ω it relates to its characteristic impedance and not any cable resistance (that you can measure with a DMM). In fact it's the square root of the ratio of the distributed inductance divided by the distributed capacitance: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}\hspace{1cm}\text{(at high frequencies)}$$

And, that ratio has the units of ohms (despite not being related to any real resistance element). A more general formula that covers all frequencies is this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}}\hspace{1cm}\text{(at low and high frequencies)}$$

At sub-audio frequencies the above formula is also purely resistive: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R}{G}}\hspace{1cm}\text{(at sub-audio frequencies)}$$

At around mid-range audio frequencies, the above formula becomes this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R}{j\omega C}}\hspace{1cm}\text{(mid-range audio frequencies)}$$

And, at those mid-range audio frequencies, the characteristic impedance is more "reactive" than at any other point in the spectrum. Graphically: -

[image]

Taken from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527610/characteristic-impedance-vs-frequency/607611#607611). The cable approximates the standard 600 Ω telephone cable.

But, we don't usually specify characteristic impedance at audio or sub-audio frequencies; we are interested in its value at high-frequencies (above 100 kHz usually).

At this point you may be confused and wonder what characteristic impedance is all about?

<sub>If you had an infinitely long piece of idealized 75 Ω coax and, applied a 12 volt supply at the near-end; the current that will flow will be 12/75 amps (160 mA). In other words, with an infinitely long cable, 160 mA will continue to flow while ever the input of 12 volts is presented.</sub>

<sub>Of course, in the real world, an infinite idealized coax doesn't exist but, for a 100 m length of coax, we could apply a short 12 volt pulse (say 100 ns in duration) and we'd expect to see a short current pulse of 160 mA. It gets more complicated after that but, in essence, that is what characteristic impedance is all about.</sub>

<sub>If you want to know how it can be calculated from 1st principles [read this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/83807/derivation-of-characteristic-impedance/83836#83836).</sub>

> *what is so special about 75 such that all coaxial cables have that
> resistance, and all speakers are usually 2,4, or 8 Ohms?*

I've explained the cable characteristic impedance.

Speakers are just simple loads and, they will have an impedance specified in the middle of the audio range (usually 1 kHz). That impedance will contain a resistive and reactive element but, we usually don't go into that much detail because, an amplifier is only concerned with driving an impedance.

Comment: The rated impedance of a loudspeaker is not usually given at 1 KHz. The frequency that's normally used is the first minimum of impedance above the first maximum of impedance. The first maximum will normally be the speaker's free air resonance, F<sub>s</sub>.

Comment: @JerryCoffin [this analog device document](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics-lab-speaker#:~:text=Typically%2C%20the%20industry%20standard%20is,coil%20acts%20as%20an%20inductor.) says 1 kHz. I'm not saying you are wrong but maybe you should link to some site that explains what you said.

Comment: https://blog.miscospeakers.com/speaker-impedance-and-oem-audio-design, especially https://blog.miscospeakers.com/hs-fs/hubfs/impedance-Frequency%20Graph.jpg?width=990&name=impedance-Frequency%20Graph.jpg

Comment: I was looking for something that definitively said *speaker impedance (as a nice round number like 8 ohms) is defined at the* the null that you describe. The blog doesn't appear to say that. Also (I guess) a mid-range speaker might be defined somewhat differently?

Comment: The real reference would be IEC 60268, but to the best of my knowledge, you have to pay to get that.

Comment: OK, I think I found some pictures that explain this. Thanks for the information @JerryCoffin

Comment: Actually, found one that states it explicitly: https://www.klippel.de/know-how/measurements/transducer-parameters/electrical-impedance.html: "The minimum of the impedance above the fundamental resonance is used for defining the nominal impedance of the speaker."

Comment: Maybe it's in this version of 60268 part 5: https://www.teknikengel.gov.tr/yonetim/api/TTEService/download/2098112/tamMetin <-- section 16 says this: *The lowest value of the modulus of the impedance in the rated frequency range shall be not less than 80 % of the rated impedance.*

Comment: See also section 19.3 (this sounds like what you have said but applies to bass-reflex speakers. Maybe there's some stuff you can add to your answer?

Comment: Looking at that, it's less useful than you'd hope. According to §3.2.1, they take the nominal impedance as being whatever the vendor specifies, and (§16.1) verify that at no point within the specified frequency range does the measured impedance fall below nominal by more than 20% (so you're allowed to round a little bit, but not much).

Comment: §19.3 isn't talking about the impedance at that point though, but the frequency at which it occurs. Other than to verify specs, I'm not sure why anybody would care much about that. I suppose you could use it to kind of vaguely estimate Q<sub>ts</sub>, but any decent spec sheet is going to specify Q<sub>ts</sub> directly.

Answer (score 8):

Speakers and cables are different beasts:

- Yes, a reasonable cable has a purely real wave impedance: The imaginary part is the loss.
- With speakers it's a bit more complicated, but the moment you feed them in an in-phase manner, you should see the real impedance.
  That's very much in compliance with what you've learned about reactive power, apparent power and effective power (Blindleistung, Scheinleistung und Wirkleistung).

> If so, what is so special about 75 such that all coaxial cables have that resistance,

Not all cables have 75Ω impedance – in fact, typically mostly consumer-grade antenna cables and cables which are only coaxial for noise reasons, not to actually transport RF, have 75Ω; lab-grade and internal cabling more commonly has 50Ω, and once you do anything on a PCB, or anything with powers that require stiff waveguides, you more re less design things that *fit your problem*, instead of using what's there.

However, standardizing of fixed cable, connector and waveguide characteristics makes sense, or else everyone would need to reinvent the coaxial connector anytime they want to connect two devices. So, 50Ω for most applications, 75Ω for low-loss long distance transport over low-cost cabling have established themselves.

Now, speakers, again, different business. Impedance of a speaker wildly varies across its frequency range. You should probably treat 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64Ω (the latter two mostly in headphones) as "this is the low-frequency, high-power operating point you should roughly (as in: power of two) design your amplifier for", not as actual impedances.

Comment: So if you were to connect your little waveguide were to face a much larger 500 Ohm cable, what would happen?

Comment: @StephenHubschrauber You'd get reflections and very little energy would make it from one cable to the other. You can use a matching network of a few passive components to fix that problem.

Comment: there's no 500Ω cables, that's higher than free-space impedance… you mean 50Ω. But Hearth is right (as they usually are)!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Transmission lines can have greater than free-space characteristic impedance. 600 ohm "ladder line" is feasible. In theory, any characteristic impedance is possible, but the required ratio of conductor spacing goes exponentially with the impedance.

Comment: @JohnDoty ah that sounds right, but yeah one tries to keep waveguides of any kind technically manageable, hence, small...

Comment: @MarcusMüller the standard telephone cable has an impedance (at mid band audio frequencies) of around 600 ohm.

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few people have already talked about cable impedance, so I'm only going to talk about loudspeaker impedance.

Let's start with what the rated impedance of a loudspeaker actually refers to. A typical loudspeaker will have an impedance curve something like this:

[image]

The tall peak there is at the free air resonant frequency of the driver, generally referred to as F<sub>s</sub>. The rated impedance is the value at the first minimum above that first maximum.

That leaves the question of why values of 2, 4, and 8 ohms are common. First of all, I'd note that at least in my experience, the most common values are probably 4, 8, and 16 ohms. 2 (and 1) Ohm have become a bit more common in car audio recently, largely because cars have fairly low supply voltage (12 Volts, nominally) but can deliver utterly massive current (more about that below).

**16 Ohm Speakers**

Back in the days of vacuum amplifiers, 16 ohms was pretty common. With a vacuum tube amplifier, that amplifier itself typically has a fairly high output impedance, so you use a transformer to match the amplifier's output to the speaker, and it's generally easier to design that transformer for somewhat higher load impedance.

**8 Ohms**

But then specsmanship entered the picture. Although it generally hurt frequency response and distortion, an amplifier designed for a 16 Ohm load could usually produce more power into an 8 Ohm load. So, last year's (obviously anemic) 10 watt amplifier became this year's (obviously much better) 18 watt amplifier, without having to waste any money on redesigning the amplifier itself at all.

About then, the Institute of High Fidelity (IHF) set some standards for amplifier specs, and at least the better quality vendors made at least some attempt at following it, so rating at still lower impedances mostly stopped, at least for home audio<sup>1</sup>.

There are a few vacuum tube amplifiers (e.g., Julius Futtermans) that drive 8 Ohm loads without a transformer, but these didn't come into use until well after 8 Ohms had become the de facto standard for home audio loudspeakers.

**4 Ohms**

4 Ohm speakers were (and still are) mostly used in car audio. Nominal supply voltage in a car is only 12 volts, so an 8 Ohm load is limited to 12<sup>2</sup>/8 = 18 watts. Reducing the load to 4 ohms allows around 36 watts instead.

Of course, there are designs that exceed that, but you need something like a high power charge pump to do it. But given a low supply voltage, the simplest way to increase power was to reduce the load impedance, so 4 Ohms became pretty much the standard.

**Even Lower Impedance**

Over the past few decades, car audio competitions have become common. One common form is simply measuring maximum volume ("SPL competition"). For this, quite a few have taken the logic above even further, so they've gone to 2 Ohm and even 1 Ohm loads. Quite a few use other strategies as well, such as massive capacitor banks so they can deliver utterly ludicrous power for a short time. For example, one is rated at 17 kilowatts (I'm tempted to make a joke about it doubling as an arc welder, but somebody would probably think that was a good idea).

---

1. Before that, some ratings were pretty outrageous. Especially cheaper vendors frequently gave peak power instead of RMS, so for a sine wave it was approximately RMS x 1.414. Not satisfied with that, some invented the term "music power" which was simply taking the measured maximum, and multiplying by 2. Then, of course, those were combined to give "peak music power", which was the measured maximum RMS power time 2.828. Then "to keep from confusing the consumer", some rounded that up to simply triple the measured power. Quite a few also based their measurements on what they could produce for only a very short period of time, but would cook the amplifier if you tried to draw that much for more than a few milliseconds. The IHF standards helped with a much of that, and the FTC later stepped in with even more rigid (and enforceable) requirements.

Comment: Early valve amplifiers were 15 ohm or 3 ohm rather than 16 or 4.

Answer (score -2):

In some cases, the impedance of a circuit or component may be purely resistive, meaning that there is no reactance present and the impedance is equal to the resistance. In this case, the value given, such as "8 Ω" or "75 Ω" is the resistance of the circuit or component.

The values of 2, 4, and 8 Ω are common for speakers because they are convenient values that are easy to work with in audio systems.

Comment: Hi, This answer isn't clear to me. Either (a) You are writing it as an *answer*, because it's the final answer to your question. If so, please "accept" an answer (green "tick"), yours or another one (if posted) to close the whole question. Or (b) You are mistakenly writing this as an *answer*, when in fact you still want replies / help. In that case, this is an *update*, not an answer, and must be "edited into" your original question i.e. click "Edit" under the question, add this update, state what help is still needed, then delete this "answer". Which applies here, (a) or (b)? Thanks.

Comment: (FYI if you do want to [accept](/help/someone-answers) your own answer as the best answer to your question, you are only able to do so [48 hours after you asked the question](/help/self-answer). If you want to accept any other answer, you can do that at any time.)

Comment: This answer seems very weak to me especially when saying that *"75 Ω" is the resistance of the circuit or component* <-- this doesn't apply to characteristic impedance (as others have explained).

Comment: 75Ω is **not** the resistance of a coax cable. So this is not "weak"; it's actually wrong. It's questionable saying that  "2, 4, 8Ω are common because they are convenient values that work with audio systems"; the opposite is at least as true: Amplifiers able to drive these impedances are common because speakers in these impedance ranges are widespread.